# In Azure,Loadbalancer details in to csv file using powershell script in pipeline of azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Csv fiile should contain ResourceGroupName,FrontendIpConfigurationsName,FrontIPAddress,VMstatus.I have written a below code.Am getting the details in csv file but the issue is FrontendIpConfigurationsName starts with same name comes in same row like ersfrontend-A1,ersfrontend-B2,ersfrontend-B3,ersfrontend-D1, and also IPs respective to the names comes in different column but in same row.But I wanted them to come different rows.Please suggest

```
report = @()
$LBlist = Get-AZLoadBalancer | Where-Object {$_ResourceGroupName -eq '*$(grp-wildcard)' } |Select-Object
$VM =Get-AzVm -Status | Where-Object {$_ResourceGroupName -eq '*$(grp-wildcard) '} |Select-Object
$power= $VM.powerstate
foreach($LB in LBlist){
Array = "" |Select-Object ResourceGroupName,FrontendIpConfigurationsName,FrontIPAddress,VMstatus
$Array.ResourceGroupName = $LB.ResourceGroupName
$Array.FrontendIpConfigurationsName =($LB.FrontendIpConfigurationsName.name -join ',')
$Array.FrontendIpAddress= ($LB.FrontendIpConfigurationsName.privateIpAddress -join ',')
$Array.VMstate = $power
}
$report+=$Array
$report |Format-Table ResourceGroupName,FrontendIpConfigurationsName,FrontIPAddress,VMstatus
$report | Export-Csv -NTI -path "$(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)/LBlist.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a proper CSV file with headers and rows of data, you need to collect an array of Objects and send that to the Export-Csv cmdlet.

For example

```
$report = @()

foreach($LB in $LBlist){
   $obj= [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ResourceGroupName '     = $LB.ResourceGroupName
            'FrontendIpConfigurationsName '   =($LB.FrontendIpConfigurationsName.name -join ',')
            'FrontendIpAddress' =($LB.FrontendIpConfigurationsName.privateIpAddress -join ',')
            'VMstate '  = $power
        }

 $report += $obj  
}

$report |Format-Table ResourceGroupName,FrontendIpConfigurationsName,FrontIPAddress,VMstatus
$report | Export-Csv -NTI -path "($BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)/LBlist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @Stella Could you please provide the screenshot of error?

Comment: @Stella Besides, could you please a working script. I cannot run your script.

Comment: There is no error. AM getting all FrontendIpConfigurationsName in one row .IPs should split in to rows like one IP in one row. They are coming in row seperated by column.I have corrected my mistakes in the code.Please check

Comment: @Stella When I run the command `$VM =Get-Az-VM`, I get the error it is not a command. Could you please check your script?

Comment: I have corrected it. *grp-wildcard is variable to which we pass vlaue of resourcegroup while running the pipeline

Comment: @Stella According to my understanding, your load balancer has some FrontendIpConfigurations and every FrontendIpConfiguration has one ip. Now these the configuration names and ip are saved in the same column. Right?

Comment: @Stella I run you sample script, I still get error. The error is `SelectObject : The term 'SelectObject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,`

Comment: yeah its Select-Object ..I have typed the code ..so its showing some errors..I aplogize for that

Comment: yes your right. load balancer has some FrontendIpConfigurations and every FrontendIpConfiguration has one ip. Now these the configuration names and ip are saved in the same column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213589/discussion-between-stella-and-jim-xu).